# Alfresco inbound rule

Tags: java, alfresco

I'm add an inbound rule to a folder in alfresco. How I can determine it's node was just created or it's was moved from another folder?

Comment: Workaround: for new nodes "cm:created" equals "cm:modified". So I'm check if "cm:created" equals "cm:modified" it's a new node.

Answer (score -1):

Next snippet can be used to add a new behaviour when a new Folder is created. This example will be triggered for every folder created in the repository. You'll have to implement what you're actually going to do with it yourself.

```
public class SalesProjectFolderBehaviour implements NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy{

/** The policy component. */
private PolicyComponent policyComponent;

/** The on create node behaviour. */
private Behaviour onCreateNodeBehaviour;

/** The service registry. */
private ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

/**
     * Inits the.
     */
    public void init()
    {
        LOG.error("initializing the behaviours");
        // Create behaviours
                this.onCreateNodeBehaviour = new JavaBehaviour(this, "onCreateNode",
                        NotificationFrequency.TRANSACTION_COMMIT);



                // Bind behaviours to node policies
                this.policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(QName.createQName(
                        NamespaceService.ALFRESCO_URI, "onCreateNode"),
                        org.alfresco.model.ContentModel.TYPE_FOLDER, this.onCreateNodeBehaviour);

    }

/* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy#onCreateNode(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ChildAssociationRef)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateNode(ChildAssociationRef childAssocRef) {
        LOG.trace("created new folder!");

    }
}
```

Comment: OP is looking for help with a folder rule, not a behavior.

Comment: Hi Jeff
Couldn't a behaviour's implementation be just like a folder rule? I know my answer wasn't an inbound rule, but it could accomplish the same thing..

Comment: Hi Qkyrie, thanks for your answer but I don't want use policy for my logic.

Comment: @Qkyrie, Yes, a behavior is similar to a rule in that you can bind it to one or more policies such that when something happens to a node your logic is triggered. But rules are end-user configurable and can be assigned to individual folders whereas behaviors require a developer to write the code, an admin to deploy, and are bound to types and aspects. As you pointed out, the behavior you suggested would run on every folder in the repo, not just the one the end-user cares about.